# UICollectionView sectionInsets not respected when using Header Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a collection view that has a header cell (dynamically sized) and some "normal" content cells (also dynamically sized). Therefore, the **collection view is initialized as follows:**

```
private lazy var timelineCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.coloredTitleBarHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) // assume that coloredTitlebarHeight is a constant of 120
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 10)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        cv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        cv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never 
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        cv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.coloredTitleBarHeight - self.getStatusBarHeight(), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.register(TLContentCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "content-header-cell")
        cv.register(TLContentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "comment-cell")

        return cv
    }()
```

The collectionView is part of a ViewController that **conforms to the following protocols**: `UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

**Then, I use the following code to create a header cell:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "content-header-cell", for: indexPath) as! TLContentCell

        cell.timelineContent = tlContentItem
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

**Last but not least, the dequeuing of the regular cells:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "comment-cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
```

### Output:

The collectionView displays the header cell as well as the item cells, however, **the section Insets are not applied.**

I would be very happy if you could provide me with any suggestion regarding this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Section insets are applied to contents only in UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

> **Using Section Insets to Tweak the Margins of Your Content**
>
> Section insets are a way to adjust the space available for laying out cells.
> You can use insets to insert space after a section’s header view and
> before its footer view. You can also use insets to insert space around
> the sides of the content. Figure 3-5 demonstrates how insets affect
> some content in a vertically scrolling flow layout. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can I then create a „top margin“? Any thoughts?